# Adsense API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, adsense

I am trying to replicate this app
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quickadsense-google-adsense/id495845748?mt=8
But i m nit sure, if there is any API or RSS or something available to keep the track of report through adsense.
Any idea ,how this app could have developed?
It shows  pageview,clicks,dailey average,country wise reports and many more.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'de start here: https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/index
 It provides some nice information about getting started on Adsense API.